# SQL Query to retrieve result without duplication

Tags: sql-server

I have table named Schedule which has fields named TeacherName and ClassTakenDate.The values in the table are as shown below:

```
TeacherName       ClassTakenDate

Anish              2011-10-01

Anish              2011-10-01

John               2011-10-01

John               2011-10-02
```

I want result like this :

```
TeacherName               NoOfDays

Anish                        1

John                         2
```

how we can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TeacherName, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT ClassTakenDate) AS NoOfDays
FROM Schedule 
GROUP BY TeacherName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TeacherName, ClassTakenDate, COUNT( * ) AS NoOfDays 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT TeacherName, ClassTakenDate
      FROM Schedule 
) AS foo
GROUP BY foo.ClassTakenDate
```

Comment: `ClassTakenDate` shouldn't be in the `SELECT` list and you would need `GROUP BY foo.TeacherName`